# Ling To Sql: Incompatible Database version

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, sql-server-ce, sqlmetal

I created a local database file (Sql Server Compact database file) in Visual Studio with the extension .sdf and I was using SqlMetal.exe to connect Linq to my Sql database file. However it gives me an error, saying that Incompatible Database Version.

```
Incompatible Database Version. If this was a compatible file, run repair. For other cases refer to documentation. [ Db version = 4000000,Requested version = 3505053,File name = \\?\C:\Database\Contact\ContactDatabase.sdf ]
```

Consider that I have Microsoft SQl Compact Server installed, both 32 and 64 bit version and I'm running on Windows 8, 64 bit. Does anyone know how to fix it ? Thanks

Comment: Per the error message, it expects a CE 3.5 database, but your database is 4.0. I don't know enough about the various versions used/included with Visual Studio to tell you how to fix that, but one easy approach would be to use Server Compact 3.5 to create the database instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must initialize your DataContext with a SqlCeConnection object for this to work, do not use a connection string.

```
var connString = "Data Source=C:\data\mydb.sdf");
var conn = new SqlCeConnection(connString);

using (var context = new MyDataContext(conn))
{}
```

Comment: and how would I do that ? Thanks

Comment: Updated reply just now